# Running a command on all files that contain a string

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I'm finding a bunch of files with `find . -exec grep -l mypattern {} \;`

What's the simplest, most elegant way to run a certain command separately on each of the resulting list of files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, use:

```
grep -Rl mypattern .
```

directly instead of the `find` construct.

What is the certain command? Probably the best and most fail-safe way would be

```
grep -ZRl mypattern . | xargs -0 mycommand
```

Exactly what you want to do is up to `xargs` from here.